# typeorm leftjoin remove parent results

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I'm using typeorm, while using leftjoin command in the querybuilder, it seems to remove the parent results:
'''

```
var user = await getRepository(Users).createQueryBuilder("user")
            .where("user.user_id = :user_id", { user_id: user_id })
            .andWhere("user.token = :u_token", { u_token: u_token })
            .leftJoinAndSelect("user.devices", "device")
            .where("device.token = :d_token", { d_token: d_token })
            .andWhere("device.code_tries <= 3")
            .andWhere("device.status = 0")
            .getMany();
```

'''
Will return the user only if there is a valid device, if no device found there will be no "user" return.

By the way, by removing all the "leftjoin" part, the user object will be returned anyway.
Like this:
'''

```
var user = await getRepository(Users).createQueryBuilder("user")
            .where("user.user_id = :user_id", { user_id: user_id })
            .andWhere("user.token = :u_token", { u_token: u_token })
            .getMany();
```

'''

The left join should return all users and the matched devices (as far as I know).
Why does this happen?

Comment: just to make clear, the problem is that if there is no matched device.. The user is not returns at all.. in my second code paragraph, with same "user" select obligation, the user returns.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your query, you might thought that the where clause after leftJoinAndSelect only applies to the device, but actually its the same as this:

```
var user = await getRepository(Users).createQueryBuilder("user")
            .leftJoinAndSelect("user.devices", "device")
            .where("user.user_id = :user_id", { user_id: user_id })
            .andWhere("user.token = :u_token", { u_token: u_token })
            .where("device.token = :d_token", { d_token: d_token })
            .andWhere("device.code_tries <= 3")
            .andWhere("device.status = 0")
            .getMany();
```

What you need is something like a subquery, one way to achieve that is using leftJoinAndMapMany:

```
const query = getRepository(Users).createQueryBuilder("user")
              .leftJoinAndSelect("user.devices", "device")
              where("user.user_id = :user_id", { user_id: user_id });

const condition = 'device.token = :d_token && device.code_tries <= 3 && device.status = 0';
query.leftJoinAndMapMany('user.devices', Device, 'device', condition, {
        d_token: d_token
    });
user = await query.getMany();
```

Comment: First of all, thanks.. it doesn't return any device, and you removed the "u_token" stands for user token, from the query.. anyway, even if I bring it back, it only returns the user without the connected device.According to you explain, The order doesn't seem to be the issue, because I specified that the "device" is a part of the left join alias.. thoughts?